# How to create a fixed header for CollectionView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my application I group all the `customers` with a `CollectionView`. This working pretty well, but I can't find any option to fix the header of the grouped items and let the user scroll down and continue to see the header. A simple graphic example:

```
|HEADER|
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

the user scroll down:

```
Item2
Item3
```

I want even display the header like that:

```
|HEADER|
Item2
Item3
```

**XAML**

The xaml structure is very simple, I have declared a `ListBox` and a `CollectionView` defined in the `Window.Resources`:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
   <Window.Resources>
       <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Customers}" x:Key="customerView">
           <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
               <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Country" />
           </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
       </CollectionViewSource>
   </Window.Resources>
   <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource customerView}}" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
public class CustomerView
{
   public CustomerView()
   {
      DataContext = new CustomerViewModel();
   }

   public class CustomerViewModel 
   {  
       public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

       //Fill the available customers
       public CustomerViewModel()
       {
           List<Customer> customers = GetCustomers();
       }
   }
}
```

this is a really simple example. And I guess the code is not really necessary, it's just for explain better the situation.

How can I keep the header even visible when the user scroll down?

Thanks for any support.

Comment: style the template. put it into a dock panel and have the header row always docked

Comment: @Steve you mean the `ListBox.GroupStyle`?

Comment: try ListView. Looks like it has already been done for u

Comment: @Steve I mean something like that: http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/header-slide.html

Comment: that you need to make your own control. And set which header should be the one docking based on scroll position